# What might cause preempt_count to change or workqueue to run in atomic context?

Tags: linux-kernel

I've been doing some module work and I'm having crashes that occur randomly (usually within 10 hours after boot).

The kernel log messages can vary from one crash to the next, but in some cases I get this:

```
<4>huh, entered c90390a8 with preempt_count 0000010d, exited with c0340000?
```

The code that generates this log is from the 2.6.14 kernel, kernel/timer.c:

```
            int preempt_count = preempt_count();
            fn(data);
            if (preempt_count != preempt_count()) {
                printk(KERN_WARNING "huh, entered %p "
                       "with preempt_count %08x, exited"
                       " with %08x?\n",
                       fn, preempt_count,
                       preempt_count());
                BUG();
            }
```

For this condition to happen, what would have had to have occurred (obviously preempt_count changed, but what might cause that)?

The other symptom of the crash is that I'm seeing a `scheduling while atomic` while doing i2c from a workqueue (which should certainly not be atomic, right?).  What might cause this?

I figure this post is a long shot but I'm really just looking for anything to troubleshoot at this point.

Answer (score 6):

Just answering from the top of my head: "preempt_count" is a 32 bit field, which are split up into sub-bit-fields for various purposes.  The sub-bit-fields are detailed in O'Reilly's Understanding the Linux Kernel.  Again, off the top of my head, I don't know what "c0340000" represents.  But since you started with "0000010d", and should have ended up with "0000010d", whatever your timer code did is pretty messed up.

One common cause is if your timer code did something like spin_lock_bh() but forgot to do a spin_unlock_bh().  But that usually results in just a 1-bit difference between the starting and ending preempt_count value.  But in your case, your starting and ending values show a massive change.

Michael

Comment: The ending value almost looks like an address.  Perhaps the code that ran in a timer is writing to random places in memory?  The module I was working in didn't have a timer but it did have a workqueue and when this issue cropped up I would see messages for scheduling while atomic from the workqueue.  At any rate, I appreciate your comment :)

Comment: Hmm, yeah, I suppose c0340000 could be an address.  But the fact that the last 4 hex digits are all 0's seems too neat for an address.  In any case, you could do a "cat /proc/modules" and see if any of the driver addresses include c0340000